# не меняется параметр .currentTime в аудио

Tags: javascript

при изменении этого параметра, он становится равным `0` и проигрывание начинается с нуля..
Вот код HTML:

```
<div class="audio-timeline">
    <div class="audio-current-timeline"></div>
    <span class="song_path" style="display:none">media/audio/Noize MC - Мое Море.mp3/</span>
</div>
<div class="audio-elements">
    <div class="audio-element play"><div class="audio-on"></div></div>
    <div class="audio-element stop"><div class="audio-stop"></div></div>
</div>
```

вот код js:

```
var timeLine = document.getElementsByClassName('audio-timeline')[0];
//отследим, куда был сделан клик по временной линии для быстрой перемотки
timeLine.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var width = timeLine.offsetWidth;
    console.log((100/width)*event.clientX);
    width = (100/width)*event.clientX;
    audioWidth = audio.duration * width / 100;
    console.log('audioWidth - ' + audioWidth);
    audio.currentTime = audioWidth;
    currentTimeLine.style.width = width + '%';
}, false);
```

Пробовал просто отключать файл js и работать с `currentTime` через консоль, он все равно при любом изменении вызывает рестарт аудиозаписи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел закономерность. Такая проблема появляется только при работе с PhpStorm. Без использования его, скрипты работают стабильно

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от задачи, может быть 2 варианта:

- меняем currentTime после загрузки аудио файла

  Здесь надо убедиться что файл загружен. Для этого можно ждать `canplay` событие. пример: http://jsfiddle.net/Andrei_Yanovich/jLeny6rt/5/

---

- меняем в процессе загрузки файла.
  Браузер использует [byte-range запросы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media#Handle_HTTP_1.1_byte_range_requests_correctly) что бы получить медиа файл с определенной позиции. Соответственно сервер должен быть сконфигурирован, что бы их обработать См. статью по ссылке выше.